# IIS7 The Application Warm-Up Module Official Release?

Tags: iis-7

I was using the IIS7 The Application Warm-Up Module Beta, which has been removed from the download site.

Please could someone tell me where I could find the official release of this module. Can't find it anywhere - thanks!

Download was available here: http://forums.iis.net/t/1176740.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the message in the link you included, the Beta has been removed due to a change in direction of the project.  There is no official release at this time.